# in SpriteKit, is it possible to enqueue actions on the fly, as if the grouping action is a mutable array

Tags: sprite-kit, action

Can I add another actions to be executed after already defined ones in a sequence-ing action. So, if I already have an

`SKAction *mySequence = [SKAction sequence:@[firstAction, secondAction]];`

Can I somehow add thirdAction to mySequence, additionaly? I know it can be done with blocks, while defining the action, but is there a way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do that with an `SKAction` sequence. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't started executing the sequence yet (ie, you haven't added them to a node for running), then it is possible.  SKAaction sequences are not mutable, but you can work around this by delaying the actual creation of the sequence and use an NSMutableArray to accumulate your SKAction objects:

```
NSMutableArray <SKActions *> *myActionsList = [NSMutableArray array];
```

and add your SKAction objects into it.

```
[myActionsList addObject:SKAction1];
[myActionsList addObject:SKAction2];
... other code...
[myActionsList addObject:SKAction3];
```

You can accumulate SKActions dynamically, then instead of using the code shown in your question to create the sequence, use

```
SKAction *mySequence = [SKAction sequence:myActionsList];
```